# Getting 'end of file' error in my bash script. What am I missing?

Tags: bash, macos

I have a large amount of files that I have just recovered from a wiped HDD and I would like to sort them into folders that are named after the files' "created" timestamp.
In the process of writing this (seemingly) simple script, I can't figure out why I get an "Unexpected End of file Error"...

```sh
cd ~/R1c/scripts/files
for file in *.{jpg,jpeg,png,gif,mp4,avi,txt}
do
    year=$(stat file | cut -d " " -f20 | tr -d '"')
    month=$(stat file | cut -d " " -f17 | tr -d '"')
    STOREDIR=${year}_${month}

    if [ -d ${STOREDIR} ]; then
        mv ${file} ${STOREDIR}
    elif
        mkdir ${STOREDIR}
        mv ${file} ${STOREDIR}
    end if
end for
```

This is run on macOS if that's important :)

Comment: Because bash closes `if` with `fi` and `for... do` with `done` (and `case` with `esac`, if it comes to that).  (You might be thinking of fish, which uses `end` everywhere?)

Comment: try : https://www.shellcheck.net/

Comment: @2e0byo I totally get what you're saying, but when I tried writing `if...fi` and `for .. do ... done`, despite running the script with `bash <script_name>`, it complains about `unexpected token 'fi'` etc...

Comment: @User123 It's funny because I just used it and it now works... :P
I would like to imagine that it was the `elif` without any statement that caused the error... I will try to figure it out :P

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply put, because there's no comparison statement after the `elif` (which should be an `else` clause) `bash` then interprets the whole thing wrong and complains about the `fi` statement instead of actually pointing out the fact that there's an `elif` without an `else`.
Thus, changing the `elif` to `else` did the trick :)